# .all() in a resolve function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reviewing the [**angular-app**](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) project I see `.all()` used in the `.config()` of modules throughout the project.

```
angular.module('projects', ['resources.projects', 'productbacklog', 'sprints', 'security.authorization'])

.config(['$routeProvider', 'securityAuthorizationProvider', function ($routeProvider, securityAuthorizationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
    templateUrl:'projects/projects-list.tpl.html',
    controller:'ProjectsViewCtrl',
    resolve:{
      projects:['Projects', function (Projects) {
        //What does this do?
        return Projects.all();
      }],
      authenticatedUser: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser
    }
  });
}])
```

Here's a [direct link](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projects/projects.js) to that source.

What is this technique used for and what does `.all()` do in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they're using a [Mongolab](https://mongolab.com/) to [ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) mapper, the `.all()` probably returns gets all items of that type (Product) from the database.

Projects is a resource created by

```
var Projects = $mongolabResource('projects');
```

UPDATE: The query is implemented [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/fcb87e3e88c650910ad6cdf9e110fdaa79f417cd/client/vendor/mongolab/mongolab-resource.js). `.all()` is basically a query with empty parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Intuition tells me this is a resource action like $get, $query etc.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)